# Replace missing value from another row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with 2 columns.

[image]

I replaced ' ' with NaN's to process faster with fillna, etc..:

```
themes = themes.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
```

How can I replace NaN's with matching values from other rows?

Comment: Did one of the solutions below help? Feel free to accept one if it did (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You need `groupby` with `ffill` and `bfill`

```
themes.groupby('code').apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
```

Comment: `themes.groupby('code').ffill().bfill()` should work (unless _every_ value is NaN inside a group) and should even be faster.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep it is true : -)

Comment: @cs95 The problem with this is that you lose the 'code' column after the `ffill()` and then pandas runs the `bfill()` on all NaNs, regardless of 'code'.

Comment: @robroc Yeah but think about this: Unless every row for a given code is NaN, the preceeding `GroupBy.ffill` step has filled everything up to and including the last of the group, so the successive `bfill()` step will only fill NaNs in its own group. You get this for free just because of how the previous `ffill` step worked. The caveat, ofc, is "unless every value is NaN inside a group" (then this does not work, hopefully you understand why!).

Comment: @c95 True, but it assumes the df is sorted so all the group values are together. I tried on data where the grouped values were scattered, and some NaN's just got whatever was below them.

Comment: @robroc it's not an unreasonable assumption because groupby sorts by keys in the output unless you pass sort=False, which, why would you.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to create a series after dropping null values.

Then use `pd.Series.fillna` with `pd.Series.map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4],
                   'name': ['A', np.nan, 'C', np.nan, 'B', 'D']})

s = df.set_index('code')['name'].dropna()
df['name'] = df['name'].fillna(df['code'].map(s))

print(df)

   code name
0     1    A
1     2    B
2     3    C
3     1    A
4     2    B
5     4    D
```